Does aa-teardown disable AppArmor permanently?
In order to disable AppArmor, I've seen advice to run this:
sudo aa-teardown

The man page says that this will unload all AppArmor profiles.
My question, is this permanent? Or will the AppArmor profiles be loaded again upon restarting the computer? How do I load the profiles again, if I don't want to restart the computer?

Yes it is permanent and you need to restore it back
If you want to just handle a bug that Apparmor makes you stop, just disabled it  by using

systemctl disable apparmor


Doesn't systemctl disable apparmor disable apparmor permanently? What is the command to undo that?

The Arch wiki says that aa-teardown only affects the current session, so I'm not sure this answer is correct.
